# ¿Cómo podría evitar los espacios en blanco usando previousSibling?

Tags: javascript

Suponiendo que tengo un elemento con un ID:

```
var elemento = document.getElementById("elemento");
<p id="elemento">Hola soy el elemento</p>
```

Ahora, que necesito reemplazar el contenido del body por su elemento anterior.

```
document.body.innerHTML = elemento.previousSibling.innerHTML;
```

Pero me encuentro que no quiero contar los espacios ya que estos mostrarían undefined, entonces podría hacer esto:

```js
var nodos = document.body.childNodes;

var u = 0,
    nl = nodos.length;

for(;u < nl ; u++) {
 if(nodos[u].innerHTML == undefined) continue;
 console.log(nodos[u].innerHTML);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hola!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Usando:

```
if(nodos[u].innerHTML == undefined) continue;
```

Para saltarme los espacios en blanco o también podria usar `previousElementSibling`

Ahora, suponiendo que no puedo usar ni el `continue`, ni `previousElementSibling`(que ignora espacios), como podría hacerlo?

Suponiendo que yo sé que existen 1 espacio en blanco de esta manera:

Entonces repito el previousSibling 2 veces, para así llegar a este, de esta manera:

```js
var b = document.getElementById("espacio");

console.info(b.previousSibling.previousSibling.innerHTML);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hola!</p> <b id="espacio">Existe solo 1 espacio</b>
</body>
</html>
```

***Todo bien, pero.. si yo no supiera cual es la cantidad de espacios, y sin usar lo que anteriormente mencioné como podría hacerlo?***

***Porque sería una tarea gigantísima repetir el previousSibling 201 veces(si hubiensen 200 espacios)***

***Lo que se me ocurre y que gran parte de eso, me trajo a preguntar esto, es que si se pudiera agregar `dinamicamente` los previousSibling, en ese caso SÍ USAR EL CONDICIONAL, osea:***

```
 if(nodos[u].innerHTML == undefined) {
// Agregar 1 previousSibling al método usado, entonces si hubiesen 5 espacios, dinamicamente quedaría como:
}
    previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling
```

Comment: ¿Cúal es una buena razón para no usar `previousElementSibling`?

Comment: Es para entender y aprender más, no para un uso determinado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías realizar un bucle en el cual fueras escalando posiciones mientras el DOM tuviera espacios. En el momento en el que el DOM te devolviera algo distinto a `undefined`, lo mostraría por pantalla.

Ejemplo:

```js
var b = document.getElementById("espacio");

while(b.previousSibling.innerHTML == undefined){
  b = b.previousSibling;
}

console.info(b.previousSibling.innerHTML);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hola!</p> <b id="espacio">Existe solo 1 espacio</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sé que la pregunta es bastante vaga, pero hay que tener en cuenta que esto funciona siempre y cuando tenga un hermano antes, y que falla si no tuviese, por ejemplo con tags anidados: `<div><span id="espacio">tag sin previousSibling</span></div>`

Answer (score -2):

Eso que quieres hacer lo podrias realizar con más facilidad usando Jquery o Prototype, yo normalmente uso Jquery

Un ejemplo seria

```
    //obtengo una copia del contenido encerrado en la etiqueta body
    var content = $('body').clone();
    //Busco todos los elementos cuyo id sea "espacio" y lo elimino
    content.find('#espacio').remove();
    //Muestro el resultado
    console.log(content.html());
```

Jquery es una libreria que te facilita mucho la manipulación del DOM, puedes encontrar las rutas aki [JQuery CDN Links](https://code.jquery.com/)

Si te embuyas en aprender un poco aki esta el [sitio oficial de la API](https://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Sinceramente, no creo que el uso de una librería como JQuery, sea necesaria para tratar este tema. Además, el OP busca algo muy concreto que es que, mediante `previousSibling` pueda saltarse los espacios. También indica con las etiquetas que solo lo quiere con Javascript.

Comment: Ok sorry solo expuse como lo solucionaria yo en mi caso.

Comment: No te preocupes, en esta vida estamos para aprender :) pero siempre es mucho mejor adaptarse a las especificaciones del OP ya que si no la gente que entra en esta pregunta buscando una respuesta concreta puede acabar confundida.